# How can I add different color overlays to each iteration of the texture in this glsl shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

So I'm working on this shader right now, and the goal is to have a series of camera based tiles, each overlayed with a different color (think Andy Warhol). I've got the tiles working (side issue - the tiles on the ends are currently being cut off ~50%) but I want to add a color filter to each iteration. I'm looking for the cleanest possible way of doing this. Any ideas?

frag shader:

```
#define N 3.0 // number of columns
#define M 3. // number of rows

#import "GPUImageWarholFilter.h"

NSString *const kGPUImageWarholFragmentShaderString = SHADER_STRING
(
 precision highp float;
 varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
 uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;

 void main()
{

    vec4 color = texture2D(inputImageTexture, vec2(fract(textureCoordinate.x * N)/(M/ N), fract(textureCoordinate.y * M) / (M/N)));

    gl_FragColor = color;


}
 );
```

Comment: Can you just send in color info with each texture coordinate that delimits your tiles?

Comment: That seems plausible but I'm not quite sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're texture is getting applied to a quad and your vertices are:

```
float quad[] = {
    0.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0, // First triangle
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    1.0, 1.0  // Second triangle
};
```

You can specify texture coordinates which corresponds to each of these vertices and describe the relationship in your vertex array object.

Now, if you quadruple the number of vertices, you'll have access to mid points between the extents of the quad (create four sub-quads) and you can associate (0,0) -> (1,1) texture coordinates with each of these subquads. The effect would be a rendering of the full texture in each subquad.

You could then do math on your vertices in your vertex shader to calculate a color component to assign to each subquad. The color component would be passed to your fragment shader. Use uniforms to specify number of rows and columns then define the color component based on which cell you've calculated the current vertex to be in.

You could also try to compute everything in the fragment shader, but I think it could get expensive pretty fast. Just a hunch though.

You could also try the GL_REPEAT texture parameter, but you'll have less control of the outcome: https://open.gl/textures

Comment: this is kind of where I was going with this initially, but I'd like to automate the process a bit further i.e. if we're multiplying the texture by 4, generate each texture with a random or pre-selected color overlay. Would like to be able to choose the multiplier on the fly.